# cattle and sheep production and reproduction records

Tags: data-request, uses-of-open-data, csv

I am looking for some records (spread sheets) that I can use for teaching/analysis. I am specifically looking for dairy/beef cattle and sheep/goat farm production and reproduction records.

Appreciate your help.

Baz

Answer (score 1):

There are several government datasets on farming/livestock.

For the UK, I would look here:
https://data.gov.uk/dataset/farming_statistics

For the USA:
http://www.ers.usda.gov/topics/animal-products/cattle-beef/

For EU:
http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/products-datasets/-/tag00044

For the World:
http://faostat.fao.org/site/569/default.aspx#ancor

Answer (score 0):

The USDA National Agricultural Statistics Service quick stats service (http://quickstats.nass.usda.gov/) can be used to download a variety of statistics at different spatial scales. For example this search is for cattle inventory by state in 2012 http://quickstats.nass.usda.gov/results/09330EBE-AC92-3D64-AFCA-7764243A87E3